# Can I inject images into a Rive animation using JavaScript?

Tags: rive

Is there a way to use JavaScript to inject an external image into a Rive animation?

For example, imagine a Rive animation where a character is holding up a blank sign. I'd like to take a user thumbnail from my website and embed it in the sign so it looks like the character is holding up a photo of the currently logged in user.

Is this possible? For example, using Rive's low-level canvas feature?